# Pagination with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I've tried pagination with AngularJS but I'm not able to implement certain things, like.

I'm able to navigate through using the '**next**' and '**previous**' but am not sure how to achieve it by just clicking on that particular '**page number**' *button*. And I also want to add focus to the particular '**page number**' *button* on clicking '**next**' and '**previous**'

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='myApp'>
    Hello World
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>

     <input type="image" src="images/btn_previous.png" alt="previous" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
    <button ng-click="currentPage = currentPage">
        {{currentPage+1 <= numberOfPages()-2 && currentPage+1 || numberOfPages()-2}}
    </button>
    <button ng-click="currentPage = currentPage">
        {{currentPage+2 <= numberOfPages()-1 && currentPage+2 || numberOfPages()-1}}
    </button>
    <button >
        {{currentPage+3 <= numberOfPages() && currentPage+3 || numberOfPages()}}
    </button> . . .
    <button >
        {{numberOfPages()}}
    </button>
    <input type="image" src="images/btn_next.png" alt="next" ng-disabled="currentPage >= data.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 5;
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.data.length/$scope.pageSize);                
    }
    for (var i=0; i<45; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }
}

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should give try to [Pagination Directive](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination)

First you need to include the module in your project:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

Then create the paginated content:

```
<ANY
dir-paginate="expression | itemsPerPage: (int|expression) [: paginationId (string literal)]"
[current-page=""]
[pagination-id=""]
[total-items=""]>
...
</ANY>
```

And finally include the pagination itself.

```
<dir-pagination-controls
[max-size=""]
[direction-links=""]
[boundary-links=""]
[on-page-change=""]
[pagination-id=""]
[template-url=""]>
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview)

Comment: thanks but I need a solution for my problem in the given code.

Comment: please give me a plunker or fiddle.

Comment: I have updated the give plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/xebTEmoTXgun7DRzflZK?p=preview

Please have a look and revert me if you have any concern

Comment: thanks a lot man! but I've got a concern, if I click on the button 8(page number) the three buttons are of the form "8,9,9" but it should stay as "7,8,9" right, since 9 is the last page? And also is it possible to make the buttons static during on-click and change only when clicking on next/prev/first/last?

Comment: I know that issue, that why i said instead of implementing our own pagination its good to utilize the one which is already build and having build release.

Comment: mm.. ok.. but will there be any copyright issues if I use his custom directives in my application?

Comment: No man, these are completely opensource thats why its public on github hence any body can use it and contribute.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [dirPagination.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js) from here. .
2. Now include dirPagination.js to your page.
3. Add angularUtils.directives.dirPagination in your module like this

> var app = angular.module("myApp",
>   ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

```
4.we use dir-paginate directive for pagination  add dir-paginate in tr tag
```

> ```
> <tr dir-paginate="event in events|orderBy:['id', 't']:true |
>      itemsPerPage: 5">
> ```

```
5.Add below given code anywhere on your page or where ever you want


 <dir-pagination-controls
            max-size="5"
            direction-links="true"
            boundary-links="true" >
        </dir-pagination-controls>
```

5. Use this code as it is ,this will automatically put buttons of

> first, next ,previous ,last

and focuses automatically on page no when clicks on button.

Answer (score 0):

1) Follow the first as per above answer and download it , next

2) Add these div part in your view page

```
<div ng-controller="PagenationController"
class="other-controller">
 <div class="text-center">
  <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true"
  on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)"
   template-url="app/views/dirPagination.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
  </div>
</div>
```

3) Add these in your controller.

```
 app.controller('PagenationController', PagenationController);
 function PagenationController($scope) {
  $scope.pageChangeHandler = function(num) {
      };
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.pageSize;
$scope.add = true;
 $scope.pageChangeHandler = function(num) {
         };
}
```